# Select in select in laravel

Tags: laravel

I recently started learning Laravel and cannot solve my problem with queries.

`SELECT * FROM films WHERE id IN (SELECT film_id FROMfavorites WHERE user_id = 2)`

This is the correct code, but how to make it for Laravel
I tried to look in documentation, but it's all not that. Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using Eloquent or Query Builder? Any specific reason or are you new to Laravel?

Comment: That's right, I'm new to Laravel

Comment: Ok mate, I'll recommend you to read these first: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent and https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries 
Your code could be as clear as `$user->favorites()->films`

Comment: Thanks mate, i will learn this method! That's very useful for me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build it as a query you can use `whereIn`

```
\DB::table('films')->whereIn('id', function($query) {
            $query->select('id')->from('favorites')->where('user_id',2);
        })->toSql();
```

this will generate

```
select * from `films` where `id` in (select `id` from `favorites` where `user_id` = ?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Eloquent` model with `whereIn()` just like below

```
Films::whereIn('id',Favorites::where('user_id', 2)->pluck('film_id'))->get();
```

and also if you use `Eloquent` model with relation, then it'll be more simple as below

```
$user->favorites()->films
```